# How do I use a Genome (string) to generate a Body (tree) that will then be controlled by a Brain (neural network) in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

## My Scenario

I have a rather large project I'm working on in Unity involving genetic algorithms and neural networks. I am just getting started and need help with my initial implementation. I am not yet using any libraries, but intend to at least try to use ml-agents in the future for part of the brain.

### My Initial Plan

My original thinking was to use a Genome that would be used to generate a Body. The Body would be a tree-like structure of Parts, with its "torso" being the "root node" of the Body. Each Part of the Body would be represented by a Chromosome and have properties (such as radius, and rotation) that would each be represented by Genes. Some properties (genes) would be Observable (inputs) by the Brain (Neural Network) and some properties (genes) would be Controllable (outputs) by the Brain.

#### Question 1

**What is the best way to represent a hierarchical tree structure as a genome?** In most implementations I've seen, the genome is represented as an array-like structure.

#### Question 2

**Is something like the following adequate for what I'm doing?** Assuming I can answer question 1, I would potentially be able to parse the Genome from a string (or some 1-dimensional structure).

```csharp
public class Gene {
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public Chromosome ChromosomeReference { get; set; }
    public Genome GenomeReference { get; set; }
    public Gene(string name, string desc) {
        Name = name; Description = desc;
    }
}
public class Gene<T> : Gene {
    public T Value;
    public Gene(string name, string desc = "") : base(name, desc) =>
        Value = default;
    public Gene(string name, T value, string desc = "") : this(name, desc) =>
        Value = value;
}
```

```csharp
public class Chromosome {
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    private Genome _genomeRef;
    public Genome GenomeReference {
        get => _genomeRef;
        set {
            _genomeRef = value;
            foreach(Gene gen in GeneDict.Values) {
                gen.GenomeReference = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public Dictionary<string, Gene> GeneDict = new();
    public Chromosome(string name, string desc = "") {
        Name = name;
        Description = desc;
        GeneDict = new();
    }
    public Chromosome(string name, List<Gene> genes, string desc = "") : this(name, desc) {
        GeneDict = new(genes.Count);
        foreach(Gene gen in genes) {
            gen.ChromosomeReference = this;
            AddGene(gen);
        }
    }
    public Gene AddGene(Gene gene) {
        if(GeneDict.ContainsKey(gene.Name)) GeneDict[gene.Name] = gene;
        else GeneDict.Add(gene.Name, gene);
        return gene;
    }
}
```

```csharp
public class Genome {
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public Dictionary<string, Chromosome> ChromosomeDict;
    public Genome(string name, string desc = "") {
        Name = name;
        Description = desc;
    }
    public Genome(string name, List<Chromosome> chromosomes, string desc = "") : this(name, desc) {
        ChromosomeDict = new(chromosomes.Count);
        foreach(Chromosome chro in chromosomes) {
            chro.GenomeReference = this;
            ChromosomeDict.Add(chro.Name, chro);
        }
    }
    public Chromosome AddChromosome(Chromosome chrom) {
        if(ChromosomeDict.ContainsKey(chrom.Name)) ChromosomeDict[chrom.Name] = chrom;
        else ChromosomeDict.Add(chrom.Name, chrom);
        return chrom;
    }
}
```

```csharp
public class TestGenome : Genome {
    public TestGenome() : base("TestGenome", new()) {
        AddChromosome(new("Body", "Chromosome for the Body"));
        ChromosomeDict["Body"].AddGene(new Gene<float>("Radius", 3f, "Body radius."));
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ChromosomeDict["Body"].AddGene(new Gene<float>($"Anchor{i}", i / 3f, $"Location of anchor point {i}"));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Question 3

Assuming that's the class structure I'm going with, **what is a good way to represent the data structure so it's easily parsable and is suitable for things like crossover?**

#### Question 4

Finally, assuming I'm using a neural network to control the generated body, **how do I link the properties of the parts to the inputs and outputs of the neural network?** Or rather, what is the best way to do so? (This part is optional because it's more of a "next step" than what I'm trying to ask now, and I realize it's probably answered elsewhere, but if you feel like helping here that would be awesome.)

Comment: Please focus on / break down to **one** question/issue at a time and avoid firing out multiple bundled questions

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to represent a hierarchical tree structure as a genome?

You can represent a tree using indices into an array:

```
public struct TreeNode{
    public int LeftNode {get;}
    public int RightNode {get;}
    // other data
}
...
int root;
TreeNode[] nodes;
```

Using an array of structs in this way can be useful since it ensures that all nodes are contiguous in memory. It can also help reduce the memory overhead of using objects. But you could use classes/objects with a common interface instead if that is preferred.

> I would potentially be able to parse the Genome from a string (or some 1-dimensional structure)

Use a library for serializing/deserializing data. I would recommend something like json, both newtonsoft and system.text.json are good. Or protobuf.net if you binary serialization. Such an array representation of a tree should be trivial to serialize for any library. If you use objects you may need to add attributes for the library to handle polymorphism, see [system.text.json example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0)